# How to make typescript throw runtime error on failed non-null assertion?

Tags: typescript, settings, assert, transpiler, non-nullable

Is there a setting to make typescript compile non-null assertions into javascript that throws an error?

By default the non-null assertion is discarded ([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMOcAUcBciDeBtAa2wGcoAnGMAcwF0TzKqBfASlwChEvEyBTKEGSQAiAB6IYxRMMQBqRHAB0ogITsm7CAmJwANr0W64VNCnQ4AntmFReYYaxZA)):

```js
// Typescript:
function foo(o: {[k: string]: string}) {
    return "x is " + o.x!
}
console.log(foo({y: "ten"}))

// Compiled into this js without warnings:
function foo(o) {
    return "x is " + o.x;
}
console.log(foo({ y: "ten" }));
// output: "x is undefined"
```

I want a setting or extension or something that makes it compile into this:

```js
function foo(o) {
    if (o.x == null) { throw new Error("o.x is not null") }
    // console.assert(o.x != null) would also be acceptable
    return "x is " + o.x;
}
```

Is there any way to convert non-null exclamation point assertions into javascript assertions or errors?

Comment: I'd say – don't use non-null assertion. Most likely you can restructure your code in such a way that you won't need them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to write your own as a macro, using something like [macro-ts](https://github.com/blainehansen/macro-ts). A feature like that will never be in typescript, since the project aims exclusively at build-time (static) type checking, as Alex Wayne explained.

Answer (score 3):

Nope.

The non-null assertion is specifically telling the compiler that *you* know better than it does. It's purely a construct for managing type information. But if you don't know better then the compiler, then you'll have to handle it yourself.

This is a feature best left avoided entirely for the sake of type safety (except for rare occassions where you can be 100% certain the value is non null), and there's even some help from eslint to let you know it's dangerous in the [`no-non-null-assertion` rule](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-non-null-assertion.md)

---

The good news, I guess, is that if you asserted the value is non null, but it is null, then your program will probably end up crashing anyway, somewhere...