# TS: Non-null assertions are not done at runtime?

Tags: typescript

I am JS developer and new to TS.  If I have the following line of code:

```
  let corners = Boolean(checkTypes[userAccess]);
```

if I change it to this:

```
  let corners = Boolean(checkTypes![userAccess]);
```

why is that frowned upon?  I had a comment saying non null assertions are not a runtime check so when would they happen?

Comment: `!` is an assertion. It tells the compiler to shut up because you (hopefully) know what you're doing. The compiler no longer checks the expression for `null` or `undefined` when you use `!`. It's *perfectly fine* if you know it is safe. If in the event that you were wrong and that the assertion was improper, you would probably get a runtime error or unexpected behavior.

Comment: If you really want runtime check (by tricks), see: \
> using something like [macro-ts](https://github.com/blainehansen/macro-ts) \
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67745384/how-to-make-typescript-throw-runtime-error-on-failed-non-null-assertion \
(though I didnt try, and feels too complex)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Non-null assertions are not done at runtime?

Correct, the JavaScript code will be just:

```
let corners = Boolean(checkTypes[userAccess]);
```

...and as a result, if `checkTypes` is nullish, that code will throw.

> so when would they happen?

They won't, unless you code them. Type assertions are just that: assertions. You're promising TypeScript that you **know** that the assertion is true. TypeScript doesn't insert code to check that you're right. You've *asserted* that you are right.

Some options for you:

1. If you want a checked assertion, you can write an [assertion function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions) *(sadly not yet documented in the handbook)*:

   ```
   function assertIsNotNullish<T>(
       value: T | null | undefined,
       message?: string,
   ): asserts value is T {
       if (value == null) { // Which checks both `null` and `undefined`
           throw new Error(message ?? `Expected non-nullish value`);
       }
   }
   ```

   Then your code would be:

   ```typescript
   assertIsNotNullish(checkTypes, "checkTypes was unexpectedly nullish");
   let corners = Boolean(checkTypes[userAccess]); // No assertion needed
   ```
2. Optional chaining and nullish coalescing (both now JavaScript features):

   ```
   // Assuming you want `false` if `checkTypes` is nullish
   let corners = Boolean(checkTypes?.[userAccess] ?? false);
   //                              ^^            ^^^^^^^^^^
   ```
3. You could have a [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates):

   ```typescript
   function isNotNullish<T>(value: T | null | undefined): value is T {
       return value != null; // Which checks both `null` and `undefined`
   }
   ```

   and then

   ```typescript
   let corners = isNotNullish(checkTypes)
       ? Boolean(checkTypes[userAccess])
       : false; // Or `true` if that should be the default
   ```

Comment: *(Sorry, if you see `assertIsNotNullish` in #3 above, hit refresh. Copy and paste error.)*

Comment: thanks T.J.  Would optional chaining alone without nullish coalescing suffice?  `let corners = Boolean(checkTypes?.[userAccess]);`  If `checkTypes` is nullish, wouldn't that compile to `let corners = Boolean(undefined);` , which would be `false` ?

Comment: @sal3jfc - Yes, that would work if you want `false` in that case. (I didn't know whether you wanted `false` or `true`, and I kind of prefer the explicitness, but as you say `Boolean(undefined)` is `false`.)